# How to get form top border height?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I know how to get the size of the screen & the working area via;

```
Rectangle rectScreen = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
Rectangle rectWorkingArea = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
```

but I couldn't find where to get the top border height of a window (winform). I think, that dimension is set by the windows operating system and cannot be changed but at least I may be able to get the height, am I wrong?

[image]

Comment: On Win10+ the border is transparent.  Try hovering the mouse near the border to see that.  So what exactly do you want to measure?  Explain why you need this and you'll get a usable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot remember the user name but the accepted (then deleted) answer was:

```
Int32 topBorderHeight = this.Height - this.ClientSize.Height;
```